# AngularJS 1.5 component $postLink and data binding

Tags: components, jquery-chosen, angularjs-1.5

I am building an Angular 1.5 component that wraps Chosen list, which needs to be initialized by calling .chosen() on the jQuery element. I can do that using the $postLink lifecycle callback, and something like $('.chosen-select').chosen(), which works fine. However, I can anticipate someone using multiple instances of the component on the same page, so using a class selector would not necessarily get the component you want.

I tried using an id selector instead, by adding a prefix to whatever id someone assigns to the component in HTML. For example, I may use the component like `<chosen-select id="roles"></chosen-select>` and in the template if have `<select id="cs-{{$ctrl.id}}">` (in the controller, I bind `id: '@'`). This all works as expected EXCEPT that in $postLink, the select element has been created (and other bindings, such as the one that lists options, resolved) but id is still "cs-{{$ctrl.id}}". At what point does that become "cs-roles" (which is what it is in the DOM when everything has been set up)? What is the best way to ensure that I am accessing the object that belongs to this component?

Here is the component code, which works:

template:

```
<select id="cs-{{$ctrl.id}}" class="chosen-select"
    ng-options="(option.name || option) for option in $ctrl.options track by (option.id || option)"
    ng-model="$ctrl.result"
>
</select>
```

component:

```
mymod.component('chosenSelect', {
  templateUrl: 'shared/components/chosenSelectComponent.html',
  controller: chosenSelectController,
  bindings: {
    id: '@',
    options: '<',
    config: '<?',
    selected: '<?',
    doChange: '&?'
  }
  });

  function chosenSelectController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.result = vm.selected || vm.options[0];

    vm.$postLink = function() {
      // would like to use ("#cscomp-" + vm.id) to make sure it is unique,
      // but id doesn't seem to have been resolved yet in select element
      $(".chosen-select")
        .chosen(vm.config)
        .on('change', function(evt, params) {
          // parms.selected also holds result
          vm.doChange({ value: vm.result });
        });
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized I could use a hierarchical selector to solve the problem. In the $postLink function, referencing $("#" + vm.id + " .chosen-select") does exactly what I want it to by narrowing the selection to only elements that are descendants of the element with the specified id.